# Laravel insert multiple input form to database

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I've been create a multiple input form like image below, and I want to save to database, the problem is when I using `dd()` it's only shown the second row data only.

How can I save each row to database?

[image]

here my laravel controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

        $input = Input::all();
        $condition = $input['service_id'];
        foreach ($condition as $key => $condition) {
            $detailorder = new DetailOrder;
            $detailorder->serivce_id = $input['service_id'][$key];
            $detailorder->order_type = $input['order_type'][$key];
            $detailorder->select_plan = $input['select_plan'][$key];
            $detailorder->qty = $input['qty'][$key];
            $detailorder->unit_price = $input['unit_price'][$key];
            //$detailorder->mandays = $input['mandays'][$key];
            $detailorder->note = $input['note'][$key];
            }
            dd($detailorder);

}
```

and here my table script, I'm using jQuery to created it

```
function getCorporateService(id){
    // get data and parsing to column
    $.get("{{ url('salesorder/service')}}/"+id, function(data){
        console.log(id);
        console.log(data);

        $.each(data, function (index, element){
            $br = "<tr id='item'>";
            $br += "<td> <input class='input-small' type='text' id='order_identifier' name='order_identifier[]' readonly></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='service_name["+id+"]' name='service_name[]' value='"+element.service_name+"' readonly>"
                        +"<input class='input-small' type='hidden' id='service_id["+id+"]' name='service_id[]' value='"+element.id+"' readonly></td>";
            $br += "<td><select id='order_type["+id+"]' name='order_type[]'> <option> - </option> <option value='add'>Add</option> <option value='change'>Change</option> <option value='cancel'>Cancel</option> </select></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='select_plan["+id+"]' name='select_plan[]'></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-mini' type='text' id='qty["+id+"]' name='qty[]' value='1' onChange='getTotalPrice("+id+")'></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='unit_price["+id+"]' name='unit_price[]' onChange='getTotalPrice("+id+")'></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='total_price["+id+"]' name='total_price[]' onChange='getTotalPrice("+id+")'></td>";
            $br += "<td><textarea class='input-small' id='notes["+id+"]' name='note[]'></textarea></td>";
            $br += "</tr>";

            $(".corporatesvc").append($br);

        });
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about your `dd` function. Currently the loop runs and vanishes all you old orders and passing the last one in your `dd function`, so you need to make an array of objects and pass it in your function like,

```
$allOrders=array(); // make an array, for storing all detail order in it
foreach ($condition as $key => $condition) {
    $detailorder = new DetailOrder;

    //you can use to ignore $key::=> $detailorder->serivce_id = $condition['service_id'];

    $detailorder->serivce_id = $input['service_id'][$key];
    $detailorder->order_type = $input['order_type'][$key];
    $detailorder->select_plan = $input['select_plan'][$key];
    $detailorder->qty = $input['qty'][$key];
    $detailorder->unit_price = $input['unit_price'][$key];
    //$detailorder->mandays = $input['mandays'][$key];
    $detailorder->note = $input['note'][$key];
    $allOrders[]=$detailorder;
}
dd($allOrders); // pass it to the function
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `public function store(Request $request)` add the line as shown below

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

        $input = Input::all();
        $condition = $input['service_id'];
        foreach ($condition as $key => $condition) {
            $detailorder = new DetailOrder;
            $detailorder->serivce_id = $input['service_id'][$key];
            $detailorder->order_type = $input['order_type'][$key];
            $detailorder->select_plan = $input['select_plan'][$key];
            $detailorder->qty = $input['qty'][$key];
            $detailorder->unit_price = $input['unit_price'][$key];
            //$detailorder->mandays = $input['mandays'][$key];
            $detailorder->note = $input['note'][$key];

            //for saving each DetailOrder to database
            $detailorder->save();
            } 
}
```

Notice here that the  `save()` should be invoked from within the `foreach` loop for saving each row to database.

Considering that your JavaScript is working properly , the above modification will save data of each row in your database.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following line:

```
foreach ($condition as $key => $condition) {
    $detailorder = new DetailOrder;
    // here you are creating a new object on each iteration, means on each iteration new object overrides old one, that's why you are getting the last record only
}
```

To solve this issue put this object creation code outside the loop and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert multi items with this code:

```
DB::table('tablename')->insert($tableitems);
```